# magento 1 to magento 2 issue migration

Tags: magento2

run command
`bin/magento migrate:data -a  app/code/Vendor/Migration/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.4.0/config.xml`
Error migration magento 1.9.4.0 to magento2 2.3.5
`Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento1.customer_entity_static' doesn't exist`

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this? 
I have same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Find a module that you are installing that is using customer_entity_static table, disable it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if You have custom attribute with `backend_type` == `static` in your `eav_attribute` table. Problem is in `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Customer/Model/AttributesDataToCustomerEntityRecords.php` file in `fetchAttributesData` method. It gets `$attributeIdsByType` and based on `type` magento refers to table (e.g. it refers to table `customer_entity_` + `backend_type` (in my, and your case it is type `static`).